# Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource in production environment

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring-boot, database-connection

I'm currently having an issue where I will get this `Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource` issue when running my application in my kubernetes cluster. When I run my spring boot web app locally with the same config file it connects without issue. Anyone know what could be the cause of this?

I've tried pulling my docker image locally and running the image locally where it works. I've tried this process on other machines and networks also. In my Kubernetes cluster though even when I SSH onto a node and run the image directly it will get this issue.

Config file:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://<url>:<port>/<dbName>
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Exception:
    2018-05-30 05:57:23.189  INFO 5 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
    2018-05-30 05:57:54.772 ERROR 5 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:990) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:342) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2188) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2221) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2016) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:776) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:386) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:117) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:123) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:365) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:194) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:460) [HikariCP-2.7.8.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:534) [HikariCP-2.7.8.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-2.7.8.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-2.7.8.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:151) [spring-jdbc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115) [spring-jdbc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78) [spring-jdbc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:318) [spring-jdbc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:355) [spring-jdbc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup.getDatabase(DatabaseLookup.java:72) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.determineDatabase(JpaProperties.java:169) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:111) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7056317a.CGLIB$jpaVendorAdapter$5(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7056317a$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$186c91d1.invoke(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361) [spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7056317a.jpaVendorAdapter(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:721) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:470) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:721) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:470) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at application.Application.main(Application.java:10) ~[classes!/:0.1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[microservice-template-0.1.jar:0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[microservice-template-0.1.jar:0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) ~[microservice-template-0.1.jar:0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) ~[microservice-template-0.1.jar:0.1]
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:211) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:301) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
    ... 93 common frames omitted

2018-05-30 05:57:54.777  WARN 5 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup           : Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource

org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Comment: Can you, in any way, verify that you can or cannot hit the database from within the Kubernetes cluster?  This is the first thing I would check.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I just did a `telnet db-address 3306` and it looks like it's timing out from my Kubernetes cluster but works from my local system. So it looks like it's actually a network problem... Not really sure how to work out what it'll be.

My Kubernetes cluster has an internet connection and DNS because it can ping addresses, e.g. `google.com`

Comment: I don't know Kubernetes at all.  If it's anything like AWS, Azure, etc., then maybe you have to open certain ports/protocols to be able to hit your database.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this. It appears that AWS had problems with bridging connections from the Kubernetes cluster to the RDS.I put the two systems on the same VPC and now it works. Thanks!